# Having trouble using EditorJS with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, editorjs

I'm experimenting with TypeScript and attemtping to use EditorJS with Typescript.  I download and installed EditorJS for my project using `npm i @editorjs/editorjs` all goes smoothly up to this point.

I then attempt to use EditorJS in my project using the line below:

```
import EditorJS from '@editorjs/editorjs';
```

However, the build fails with the messages :

```
Cannot find type definition file for 'data-formats'
```

and

```
Cannot find module '@editorjs/editorjs'
```

The folder `module_modules/@editorjs` does exist in my project so I can't figure out what the problem may be here.

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction

Below is an outline of my project structure:

```
-/node_modules/
    -- /@editorjs
    -- /editorjs
-/src/
    -- /@types/
    -- Main.ts
- package.json
```

I've omitted all other folder unrelated to editorjs

My tsconfig.json is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "ES2017",
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "sourceRoot": "./src/",
    "rootDir": "./src/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",    
    "typeRoots": [
        "./node_modules/@types",
        "./src/@types/",
        "./node_modules/@editorjs/editorjs/types"       
    ]       
  }
}
```

in packakge.json I have added the following dependency:

```
"@editorjs/editorjs": "^2.17.0",
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us your project structure

Comment: @Supercool editied my question to include project structure, let me know if you need anything further for clarification

Comment: in package.json you need not add the entry manually. While installing just use --save at the end of the command.

Comment: @Supercool that entry was actually added automatically when I installed editorjs via npm

Comment: add also tsconfig.json to your question

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-d8nl9j its perfectly working here...its an issue with tsconfig

Comment: Added tsconfig.json to my question, now during the build I get the error: `TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'data-formats'.`

Answer (score 1):

type in the import statement EditorJS should be CamelCase.

change

```
import EditorJS from '@editorjs/editorjs';
```

to

```
import **EditorJs from '@editorjs/editorjs';
```

Comment: It would be useful to point out that the change is one of `JS` to `Js`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the tsc configuration. It seems you are using types from src/@types and node_modules folder is jot included

Comment: I adjusted my tsconfig to add the following to the "typeRoots" array : `"./node_modules/@editorjs/editorjs/types"` which now gives the error: `Cannot find type definition file for 'data-formats'`

Comment: Try to specify just ./node_modules/@editorjs/editorjs, there is a "types" field in the package.json referring to types folder

Comment: I get a different error if I try that: `Cannot find type definition file for 'dist'.`

Comment: This problem not related to EditorJS itself I guess.

Comment: We used declaration template for class-module: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-class-d-ts.html. The problem appears because of typeRoots override, you need to configure your tsconfog properly